# How to play more than one video in cocoa touch?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to play more than one video at the same time in Cocoa Touch.

I can play one video with MPMoviePlayerController, but it does not allow to play more than one: "Note: Although you can create multiple MPMoviePlayerController objects and present their views in your interface, only one movie player at a time can play its movie."

Basically I'm trying to display complex, high resolution animation in a loop with autostart, but using PNGs makes the app size way too big (+500 MB)

I converted one object of the animation to a movie which is about 50x smaller now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its not possible to play two video at the same time. But you can play video in queue refer [this article....](http://cocoabugs.blogspot.com/2010/12/playing-movies-or-videos-in-queue-using.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have to play back at the same time :(